When should I apply Benjamini-Hochberg vs. Benjamini-Yekutieli FDR correction?
I have barely heard of people using the BY procedure for FDR correction, with BH being much more common. However, as I understand it the BY procedure is more robust to various dependency structures, while BH assumes independent tests.
There are tons of applications in which interdependency is a very plausible assumption, yet authors use BH for FDR correction. Anecdotally, BY appears to be more stringent than BH (generates higher adjusted Padj values).
For which types of dependency structure is a BH test still valid?
Would appreciate pointers to suggested reading for a biological scientist (ie not statistician).

This page has some detailed discussion of the differences between these tests. As the formulas in the Wikipedia section on procedures for controlling false discovery rate (FDR) show, the Benjamini-Yekutieli (BY) procedure is the same as the Benjamini-Hochberg (BH) procedure "if the tests are independent or positively correlated" and otherwise (negative correlations) BY is more conservative than BH unless there is only one comparison (and thus no correction is necessary).
One question is how you will be using the FDR. Typically FDR values are used to highlight the "most significant" set of genes (or proteins, or metabolites, etc.) that were altered in some experimental procedure. The choice of FDR correction in that case might affect how many genes show up in a summary table, but today one typically presents all the data in supplemental material so that others can re-evaluate as they wish. Furthermore, many associated analyses, like Gene Set Enrichment Analysis, use results for all genes. In that situation there's certainly no harm in using the BH procedure provided that one recognizes that the true FDR might not correspond to what you specified in the call to your function. The ordering among genes will be the same whether you use BH or BY.
If you are interested, there are many more ways to control FDR, with many evaluated by Korthauer et al., Genome Biology 20, Article number: 118 (2019). Notably, they didn't include BY but they did include the q-value method of Storey and Tibshirani, implemented in the Bioconductor q-value package, as another "classic" procedure.
One reason not to get too hung up on the specific FDR values is that, in practice, other sources of variation can be so important that the original p-values on which they are based might not be very reliable to begin with. I'd suggest that you look at the Bioconductor sva package, which "contains functions for removing batch effects and other unwanted variation in high-throughput experiment." The documentation shows how to combine those methods with FDR correction for improved performance. Although Storey is an author of that package, Section 5 of the vignette uses BH for FDR control.

Thank you for your thorough reply - appreciate the help!
